# Injective type families and constraints

Tags: haskell, type-families

Lets say we've got some existing class or constraint `C`, and the following:

```
{-# TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

type family F t = s | s -> t

type D s = (s ~ T t, C t)
```

Of course `type D s ...` fails to compile because of the unknown variable `t`, but how can I write something like `D s`? I basically want to write:

```
type D s = (C (T_Inverse s))
```

Which I think should be valid as because of injectivity `T_Inverse` exists. I just don't know how to express it.

Answer (score 5):

The best I know how to do is

```
type family FI a
type D s = (s ~ F (FI s), C (FI s))
```

You'll have to form the (possibly partial) section `FI` yourself, so I don't think the injective type family really helps. Injective type families seem quite limited and unnatural at this point. To take an obvious example, GHC won't even accept that they're injective!

```
blah :: F a ~ F b => a :~: b
blah = Refl
```

does not pass the type checker.

Comment: The fact that second example doesn't compile is really annoying.